# Bitmap - Matrix operations (scale, rotate and translate)

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas

I need some help with matrix operations. What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Scale down
- Move to a specific position
- Rotate by some degree (in the center of the bitmap)

My code currently looks like this:

```
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preRotate(mShip.getRotation(), mShip.getX() + mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()/2f, mShip.getY()  + mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()/2f);
            matrix.setScale((1.0f * mShip.getWidth() / mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()), (1.0f * mShip.getHeight() / mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()));
            matrix.postTranslate(mShip.getX(), mShip.getY());
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mShip.getCurrentBitmap(), matrix, mBasicPaint);
```

But the rotation has the wrong center, and I can't figure out how to solve this - I've already looked around on SO but did only find similar problems, no solutions to this. 
I think that I might have to apply one of the operations to another one's values as they are executed in a sequence but I cant figure out how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(-mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()/2f, -mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()/2f);
matrix.postRotate(mShip.getRotation());
matrix.postTranslate(mShip.getX(), mShip.getY());
matrix.postScale((1.0f * mShip.getWidth() / mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()), (1.0f * mShip.getHeight() / mShip.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()), mShip.getX(), mShip.getY());
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the translation is too far top and in the back. I fixed it by changing postTranslate to postTranslate(getX() + getWidth()/2f, getY() + getHeight()/2f) and now it works! Thank you very much. Could you give me a hint/explanation why these two translations are needed?

Comment: First translate is needed to move image center to (0,0), so it could be rotated around it's center. After this operation it can be moved to the destination point and scaled.